# Entity Framework select items with condition from another table

Tags: entity-framework

I have a question in Entity Framework.

I have two tables: `Customers` and `Addresses`

The `Customers` table contains information about customers and `Addresses` contain information about the customer address. Both tables are linked together by `CustomerID`.

How can I get all `Customers` objects (from `Customers`) who are living in the USA (from `Addresses`) ?

Can anyone help?

Comment: What have **you tried** so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: well, since i am a beginner. I have just queried both tables separately and then combined them both in a new Customers list. It works, but it's a long unprofessional process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.Where` like this:

```
List<Customer> usaCustomers = dbcontext.Customers.Where(c => c.Address.Country == "USA");
```

This assumes that:

- Each customer has only one address
- Address entity has `Country` property